# Android - How to do string interpolation?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently developing an app just for hobby. After some time, I have encountered that it's kind of annoying to manage text with dynamic content because you always have to update entire texts instead of just the dynamic portion.

So I was wondering if there is some way to have something like php or jsp where we can do something like this:

```
<p><?php echo getDays(); ?> days without accidents</p>
```

Just to clarify, I know this may not be a good practice and it sort of break the MVC architecture, but as far as I know, Stackoverflow doesn't have a policy against questions that may have bad practices as solutions. 
Consider it is just for the sake of knowing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this [documentation on string resources](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#FormattingAndStyling) is what you were looking for?

Comment: That is exactly what i was talking about. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @[0x0nosugar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5015207/0x0nosugar) stated, the answer was right on the Android string resources reference. So to achieve this we will go with something like

**string.xml**

```
<string name="welcome_messages">Hello, %1$s! You have %2$d new messages.</string>
```

And then on the Activity

**MainActivity.java**

```
Resources res = getResources();
String text = res.getString(R.string.welcome_messages, username, mailCount);
```

And then we just combine this with `mEditText.setText(text);`